# Using Apache HttpClient for an OPTIONS request

Tags: java, http, apache-httpclient-4.x, http-options-method

I am trying to use httpclient to verify if a specific **endpoint** is reachable. It seems that it is only possible to check if the server is up but cannot verify if the actual resource is available.

Here is my code:

```
HttpClient client = new Default HttpClient();

client.execute(new HttpOptions(url)).getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

According to the protocol (http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) it should have been checking the status of the specific resource but I always get a 200 response as long the the actual host is reachable. What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you.

Comment: What server is used? My guess is that the Options method is not really supported by the server.